# How to handle large amount of MySQL Select. Multi Select possible?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

A script outputs a value from a MySQL database.
query:

```
SELECT data FROM db WHERE a = b
```

The table is like:

```
ID-data-a
1-AAA-Foo
2-BBB-Foo
3-CCC-Foo
4-DDD-Bar
```

This script is called about 500 times a second. Therefore I am a little bit concerned about the MySQL-Server performance.

Is it possible to change the query so that all data is queried in **one** go? So the necessary calls could be reduced.

So I am looking for something like:

```
SELECT data[row1], data [row2], data[row3] FROM db WHERE a = "Foo"
```

Getting the result AAA, BBB, CCC

Comment: Whats' the logic for lumping 3 rows? Is it just by the last node of the column ID-data-a or is there more to it than that?

Comment: I have to check the value of multiple rows to insert the "data" to the value of different textboxes. Therefore its necessary that every "data" is stored in a seperat row in the DB.  "A" is the Username the Content belongs to.

Comment: why is it being called 500 times a second?  It would probably be helpful to see the code for getting the data/making the calls